# Query Camera Vendor's DirectShow filter for Region (Area) of Interest functionality

Tags: c++, video, camera, directshow

Some cameras allow you to set the region of interest so as to increase the camera frame rate.

What I would like to know is what would be the best way to query a DirectShow filter provided by a vendor so as to programmatically set and clear the camera region of interest.

Would code to do this be specific to the particular vendor's filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is untypical for a camera, for a video source to use ROI and especially to increase frame rate by capturing smaller region (even though it makes sense in general). So the code will be vendor specific and most likely with the use of vendor SDK or otherwise model specific interfaces/extensions.

Comment: So what I understand is that when vendors are creating a filter for a particular model of camera they will implement some standard DirectShow interfaces but also implement there own interface for camera specific features such as ROI. My application is designed mostly for machine vision cameras that provide a DirectShow filter. For these cameras (I think) ROI is often provided but not for standard cameras (as you say). If I am right in my understanding, how then to support ROI for cameras that offer it? As their methods will be different???

Comment: Further to the above comment, it would seem that I would need to consult each camera model's documentation to determine the appropriate method calls and write model specific code...am I right???

Comment: Baseline capture does not assume that you apply ROI. You capture full frame and then you are free to crop a ROI as you like. This certainly does not let you constrain bandwidth and increase frame rate, if bandwidth is the bottleneck (such as with USB 2.0 bandwidth). If camera does support ROI, you need to check with the vendor how to set it up with the camera exactly provided that you consume video capture using DirectShow API.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am testing with a Thorlabs DCC1545M camera which allows you to set what I would call 'hardware ROI'. Full frame it is 1280x1024 but only at 10 fps on my machine, set small ROI and it jumps up to as much as 100 fps. However, inspecting the image buffer shows that while the buffer is the same size, only ROI bytes are set. However, I do not have experience with other cameras (consumer or machine vision). Is it true to say then that machine vision cameras often do not offer this kind of hardware ROI e.g. they only offer software ROI?

Comment: To my best knowledge software ROI is the only option you have with a generic camera. It is technically possible to include ROI rectangle with the negotiated media type. I am not aware of cameras that pay attention and pick it as ROI. This Thorlabs camera might be using this or different method. I would check with their support/representative how to setup ROI programmatically with their products. You will possibly try the same method with other products (unless the information you get makes it sure the method is product specific).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I will accept your answer. And thanks for your help with the additional ROI issue. I will need to inspect the documentation for other vendor models and see if their DirectShow interface offers features that are not  offered by DirectShow as standard. If a camera does not offered this 'hardware' ROI then, as far as I am aware, I can just implement my own software ROI and bypass the whole issue.